# Can I add HubSpot's blog as origin in my CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

Let's pretend `example.com` is my domain.

I'd like to have:

- HubSpot's provided landing page at `example.com/`
- HubSpot's provided blog at `example.com/blog/`
- my website hosted on AWS S3 at `example.com/map/`

So, I'm thinking about adding HubSpot's origins to my CloudFront distribution and configuring my distribution's behaviors to point to the appropriate origins based on path like this:

- `/` -> `1234567.group1.sites.hubspot.net`
- `/blog` -> `1234567.group1.sites.hubspot.net/blog`
- `/map` -> `my-map-platform.website.s3.amazon.com/map`

Is it OK to have CloudFront in front of HubSpot provided websites? Are there any problems connected with this approach?

Comment: Hey, it should be all right to use these as an origin. If I may suggest one slight modification it would be to rather than using the endpoints directly as origin add them through a DNS entry. For Example:
1234567.group1.sites.hubspot.net becomes origin.example.com and then you add origin.example.com to your cloudfront origins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HubSpot employees stated at their forum that they don't support this approach and though it may work at the beginning, many requests from the same IP may get this IP blocked over time.